# Why is Row widget not accepting a list?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, widget

I am trying to display a list of icons by creating a List of Widgets and passing that list to a Row. But Row widget is not accepting that List.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Quizzler());
}

class Quizzler extends StatelessWidget {
  const Quizzler({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
            child: QuizPage(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class QuizPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const QuizPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _QuizPageState createState() => _QuizPageState();
}

class _QuizPageState extends State<QuizPage> {
  List<Widget> scoreKeeper = [
    Icon(
      Icons.check,
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    Icon(
      Icons.check,
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    Icon(
      Icons.close,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
    Icon(
      Icons.close,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 5,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'This is where the question text will go.',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25.0,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                'TRUE',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                'FALSE',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            scoreKeeper,
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

There is an error when i try to specify the scoreKeeper in the children of Row.
This is what the error looks like,
**The element type 'List' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.**

**Error image**
[image]

Comment: Haven't looked properly, but try removing the square brackets around scoreKeeper in the Row. At the moment, scoreKeeper must be a widget because it's already inside a List. If this answer worked, please tick my real answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the square brackets around `scoreKeeper` in the Row. At the moment, `scoreKeeper` must be a widget because it's already inside a List.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `[]` it expects child(single widget), but you are passing children(multiple).
It can be solved in these ways:

```dart
                   Row(
                    children: scoreKeeper,
                  ),
```

```dart
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      ...scoreKeeper.toList(),
                    ],
                  ),
```

```dart
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      ...scoreKeeper.map((e) => e).toList(),
                    ],
                  ),
```

I prefer using 1st or last answer.
Does it solve your problem?